# Routing issue for spanish accent url

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have  a link like :

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->basepath(); ?>/blog/
 <?php echo utf8_encode($item['category_name']); ?>">
 <?php echo utf8_encode($item['category_name']); ?>
</a>
```

Here $item['category_name'] coming from database like : Artículos 
after a click on this, we are calling this route given bellow

```
        'faq' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/blog[/:cat_name][/]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'blog',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

but it's returning me the error because of Spanish accent when I change the URL from Artículos tp Articulos it's working fine
I am googling but not able to find a proper solution can anyone just help me related this ?? thanx in advance

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Statement could not be executed (HY000 - 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=')

Comment: It sounds like `urlencode` would help you with this.

Comment: i tried but not working in my case

Comment: i think i have an issue with route

Comment: What collation is your database set to? usually setting it to `UTF8` should work.

Comment: you just need to allow all the special character in the constraint of the route

Comment: Then and then it will match other wise it will give an error

Comment: just make it .* at the end you have to just find the category from database if it is not there then a 404. This should resolve the issue i guess